# Validating credit card numbers - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and doing the exercises from http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html.

This is my code to validate credit cards as described on http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/01-intro.pdf.

I know very little about it and welcome any advice on how to improve.

Here's my solution:

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits x
  | x <= 0 = []
  | otherwise = toDigits (div x 10) ++ [mod x 10]

toDigitsRev :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsRev x
  | x <= 0 = []
  | otherwise = (mod x 10) : toDigitsRev (div x 10)

doEveryTwo' :: (t -> t) -> [t] -> [t]
doEveryTwo' _ [] = []
doEveryTwo' f (x:xs) = x : doEveryTwo f xs

doEveryTwo :: (t -> t) -> [t] -> [t]
doEveryTwo _ [] = []
doEveryTwo f (x:xs) = f x : doEveryTwo' f xs

doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther xs
  | length xs `mod` 2 == 0 = doEveryTwo (*2) xs
  | otherwise = head xs : doEveryTwo (*2) (tail xs)

sumDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumDigits [] = 0
sumDigits (x:xs) = sum (toDigits x) + sumDigits xs

validate :: Integer -> Bool
validate x
  | x < 10 = False
  | otherwise = sumDigits (doubleEveryOther (toDigits x)) `mod` 10 == 0
```

Comment: Err, do you know the `(.)` operator yet? Otherwise I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

1. `toDigits` can be expressed with `toDigitsRev` and vice-versa.
2. If you use both `div` and `mod`, use `divMod` to get both at the same time.
3. You can pattern match on two elements in a list with `(x:y:xs)`. That way you only need a single `doEveryTwo`.
4. `sumDigits` is `sum . map (sum . toDigits)`.
5. `doubleEveryOther` can be written with `mapAccumR`, but that might be a little bit too advanced.

---

All in all, your code will work, but we can improve it.

## Write functions in terms of other functions

You have written both `toDigits` as well as `toDigitsRev`. However, you only need one of them. The other one is the `reverse`d variant:

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits = reverse . toDigitsRev
```

## Use `divMod` if you need both results

You can think of `divMod` as

```
divMod x y = (div x y, mod x y)
```

but it's usually faster. Even better, if all your numbers are guaranteed to be positive, use `quotRem`, since `div` and `mod` have some constraints on their result:

```
toDigitsRev :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsRev x
  | x <= 0 = []
  | otherwise = r : toDigitsRev q
 where
  (q,r) = x `quotRem` 10 -- x guaranteed to be positive
```

## Use pattern matching to your advantage

You can match on multiple elements in a list at once. That way, you can write `doEveryTwo` without a helper that skips:

```
doEveryTwo :: (t -> t) -> [t] -> [t]
doEveryTwo f (x:y:xs) = f x : y : doEveryTwo f xs
doEveryTwo _ [x]      = f x
doEveryTwo _ []       = []
```

Note that a worker-wrapper approach is usually used here for performance:

```
doEveryTwo :: (t -> t) -> [t] -> [t]
doEveryTwo f = go
  where
    go (x:y:xs) = f x : y : go xs
    go [x]      = f x
    go []       = []
```

That way we don't have to carry `f` along. (**Exercise:** write `doEveryTwo` with `zipWith`. Have a look at `cycle` if you get stuck).

## Use higher order function to your advantage

When you do the same for all elements in a list, it's usually time to use `map`. If we take a look at `sumDigits`, we can see that it uses `toDigits` for all numbers and then sums it:

```
sumDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumDigits [] = 0
sumDigits (x:xs) = sum (toDigits x) + sumDigits xs
```

If we write that as list comprehension, it gets more obvious:

```
sumDigits xs = sum [sum (toDigits x) | x <- xs]
```

That's the same as

```
sumDigits xs = sum (map (sum . toDigits) xs)
```

or

```
sumDigits = sum . map (sum . toDigits)
```